# BCS custom connector and incremental crawl with search server express not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, bcs, search-express

we are currently developing a generic connector framework to access JSON-resources from an HTTP-Server. As the connector should not depend on a data model it heavily relies on DynamicType.  As there is a large amount of data in the external system and an timestamp is provided, we chose to use the cookie filter approach to implement and ChangedIdEnumerator for incremental crawls. For a full crawl we use an IdEnumerator-Method on every entity. The .bdcm-Model (there are more entities in the original model) looks the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog" 
 Name="SalesModel">
<LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Name="BpnConnectorLOB" Type="Custom">
       <Properties>
          <Property Name="SystemUtilityTypeName" Type="System.String">BpnSharepoint.Connector.BpnConnector,...</Property>
          <Property Name="SystemUtilityInstallDate" Type="System.DateTime">2012-01-01 00:00:00Z</Property>
          <Property Name="InputUriProcessor" Type="System.String">BpnSharepoint.Connector....</Property>
          <Property Name="OutputUriProcessor" Type="System.String">BpnSharepoint.Connector....</Property>
  </Properties>
  <LobSystemInstances>
    <LobSystemInstance Name="BpnSharepointModel">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="BpnRemoteBaseUrl" Type="System.String">http://localhost:8080/</Property>
        <Property Name="DebugOutputEnabled" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
        <Property Name="AuthenticationType" Type="System.String">Credentials</Property>
        <Property Name="SsoApplicationId" Type="System.String">BpnConnector</Property>
      </Properties>
    </LobSystemInstance>
  </LobSystemInstances>
  <Entities>
    <!-- ############### -->
    <!-- ### Contact ### -->
    <!-- ############### -->
    <Entity Name="Contact"
            DefaultDisplayName="büro+ Kontakt"
            Namespace="BpnSharepoint.Connector.BpnSharepointModel"
            Version="1.0.0.4">

      <Properties>
        <Property Name="Title" Type="System.String">FullName</Property>
        <Property Name="DefaultAction" Type="System.String">Default</Property>
      </Properties>

      <Identifiers>
        <Identifier Name="Id" TypeName="System.String" />
      </Identifiers>

      <Methods>

        <!-- Contacts-ID-Enumerator-Methode starten-->
        <Method Name="Read Contact Ids" DefaultDisplayName="Alle büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="Id Enumerator List">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="IdEnumerator" 
                            Name="Id Enumerator" 
                            DefaultDisplayName="Alle büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen" 
                            ReturnParameterName="Id Enumerator List" 
                            Default="true">
              <Properties>
                <!--<Property Name="BatchByDefault" Type="System.Boolean">true</Property>-->
                <Property Name="RootFinder" Type="System.String">true</Property>
              </Properties>
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Contacts-ID-Enumerator-Methode beenden-->

        <!-- Changed-ID-Enumerator-Methode starten-->
        <Method Name="Read Changed Contact Ids" DefaultDisplayName="Geänderte büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts</Property>
          </Properties>
          <FilterDescriptors>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String" />
              </Properties>
            </FilterDescriptor>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="Timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
          </FilterDescriptors>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="InOut" Name="Last Crawl Date">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="Last Crawl Date" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                <Interpretation>
                  <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local"/>
                </Interpretation>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="Id Enumerator List">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="ChangedIdEnumerator" 
                            Name="Changed Id Enumerator" 
                            DefaultDisplayName="Geänderte büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen" 
                            ReturnParameterName="Id Enumerator List"
                            Default="true">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Changed-ID-Enumerator-Methode beenden-->

        <!-- Deleted-ID-Enumerator-Methode starten-->
        <Method Name="Read Deleted Contact Ids" DefaultDisplayName="Gelöschte büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts</Property>
          </Properties>
          <FilterDescriptors>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String" />
              </Properties>
            </FilterDescriptor>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="Timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
          </FilterDescriptors>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="InOut" Name="Last Crawl Date">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="Last Crawl Date" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                <Interpretation>
                  <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local"/>
                </Interpretation>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="Id Enumerator List">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="DeletedIdEnumerator" 
                            Name="Deleted Id Enumerator" 
                            DefaultDisplayName="Gelöschte büro+ Kontakt-Ids lesen" 
                            ReturnParameterName="Id Enumerator List"
                            Default="true">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Deleted-ID-Enumerator-Methode beenden-->

        <!-- Read Contacts-Methode starten -->
        <Method Name="Read Contacts" DefaultDisplayName="Alle büro+ Kontakte lesen">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="Contact List">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CustomerId" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Title" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="LastName" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="FirstName" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressStreet" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressPostalCode" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressCity" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CompanyName" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessFaxNumber" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="PrimaryTelephoneNumber" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessTelephoneNumber" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="MobileTelephoneNumber" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessHomePage" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Email1Address" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="Finder" Name="Read List" DefaultDisplayName="Alle büro+ Kontakte lesen" ReturnParameterName="Contact List" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="Nodes" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Read Contacts-Methode beenden -->

        <!-- Read Contact-Methode starten -->
        <Method Name="Read Contact" DefaultDisplayName="Einen büro+ Kontakt lesen">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts/{Id}</Property>
            <Property Name="DescriptionField" Type="System.String">FullName</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="In" Name="Id">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" />
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="Contact">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Id" Name="Id" ReadOnly="true" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CustomerId" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Title" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="LastName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="MiddleName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="FirstName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="FullName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="NickName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressStreet" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressCity" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressPostalCode" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressState" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressCountry" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressPostOfficeBox" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressStreet" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressCity" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressPostalCode" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressState" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressCountry" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressPostOfficeBox" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="JobTitle" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Profession" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Department" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CompanyName" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessFaxNumber" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="PrimaryTelephoneNumber" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessTelephoneNumber" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="MobileTelephoneNumber" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessHomePage" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Email1Address" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Email2Address" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Body" />
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="SpecificFinder" Name="Read Item" DefaultDisplayName="Einen büro+ Kontakt lesen" ReturnParameterName="Contact" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="Node" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Read Contact-Methode beenden -->

        <!-- Update Contact-Methode starten -->
        <Method Name="Update Contact" DefaultDisplayName="Einen büro+ Kontakt ändern">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="MethodUrlPath" Type="System.String">/contacts/{Id}</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="In" Name="Id">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Id" PreUpdaterField="true" />
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="In" Name="Contact">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CustomerId" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Title" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="LastName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="MiddleName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="FirstName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="FullName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="NickName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressStreet" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressCity" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressPostalCode" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressState" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressCountry" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessAddressPostOfficeBox" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressStreet" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressCity" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressPostalCode" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressState" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressCountry" UpdaterField="true" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="HomeAddressPostOfficeBox" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="JobTitle" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Profession" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Department" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="CompanyName" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessFaxNumber" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="PrimaryTelephoneNumber" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessTelephoneNumber" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="MobileTelephoneNumber" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="BusinessHomePage" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Email1Address" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Email2Address" UpdaterField="true"/>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Body" UpdaterField="true"/>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="Updater" Name="Update Item" DefaultDisplayName="Einen büro+ Kontakt ändern" Default="true">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!-- Update Contact-Methode beenden -->

      </Methods>


      <Actions>

        <Action Name="Default"
                Position="1"
                Url="/bpnconnector/entities//Contact.aspx?Id={0}"
                IsOpenedInNewWindow="false">
          <ActionParameters>
            <ActionParameter Index="0" Name="Id" />
          </ActionParameters>
        </Action>

      </Actions>

    </Entity>


  </Entities>
```

A full crawl works like a charm but puts heavy load on the machine. When I write trace messages to ULS or attach to mssdmn.exe I see that in full crawls the ChangedIdEnumerator, DeletedIdEnumerator and IdEnumeratorMethod is called, then some LobUri and INamingContainer-magic happens and onwards the SpecificFinder is called for every Id returned from IdEnumerator.

When I start a incremental crawl with attached debugger, I see that the ChangedIdEnumerator is called with the right cookie argument. My ChangedIdEnumerator-Impl looks the following:

```
private void ExecuteChangedIdEnumerator(IMethodInstance mi, ILobSystemInstance si, object[] args, IExecutionContext context)
{
    var cookie = Convert.ToDateTime(args[0]);
    var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    var ret = new List<DynamicType>();

    var methodUrl = BuildUrlFromLobSystemAndMethod(si, mi, true, int.MaxValue);
    methodUrl = AppendUpdatedMinParamForChangedIdEnumerator(methodUrl, cookie);

    var creds = GetRemoteCredentials(si);

    var jsonStr = methodUrl.DownloadJsonFromUrlWithCreds(creds);
    var jsonArray = JsonArrayObjects.Parse(jsonStr);

    foreach (var jsonObj in jsonArray)
    {
        var dynType = new DynamicType();
        dynType.PopulateNeccessaryTypeDescriptorsWithDictionary(mi, jsonObj);

        ret.Add(dynType);
     }

     args[0] = timestamp;
     args[1] = ret;
}
```

That is more or less the same as my IdEnumerator, but adds the cookie to the HTTP-query-url and has two arguments (one for the cookie INOUT, and the changed ids RETURN). The logic to build the DynamicType-collection with the Id-Fields is exactly the same for IdEnumerator and ChangedIdEnumertor. As far as I can say from debugging the method works right (as the IdEnumerator).

The Problem is now, that nothing happens after I returned the changed ids. The DeletedIdEnumerator, isn't called. No LobUri or INamingContainer methods are called. In ULS log I get the following suspicious entry:

```
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                          0x2C4C   SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI                        e5e0    High        advising status change NSC_FLUSH (b9a315d3-1e4b-4ffb-8366-9e5cd5c5f0bb-crawl-0 Portal_Content crawl -1)  [gatherobj.cxx:4514]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx    
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                       0x2C4C  SharePoint Server Search        GatherSvc                       fus3    Medium      Transaction failed in plugin RHTG Url bpnshelf://contacts Error 0x80004003      [gthrtrx.cxx:1042]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\gthrsvc\gthrtrx.cxx    
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                       0x16CC  SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI                        dww2    Medium      processing status change (1) NSC_FLUSH, (b9a315d3-1e4b-4ffb-8366-9e5cd5c5f0bb-crawl-0, Portal_Content) thread id 0x16cc  [statthrd.cxx:97]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\server\statthrd.cxx    
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                       0x16CC  SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI                        dra4    High        CGthrPrj::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content b9a315d3-1e4b-4ffb-8366-9e5cd5c5f0bb-crawl-0 )  [cgatherprj.cxx:1698]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\gthrsvc\cgatherprj.cxx  
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                       0x16CC  SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI                        ds7h    High        CPluginCollection::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content b9a315d3-1e4b-4ffb-8366-9e5cd5c5f0bb-crawl-0 )  [plugin.cxx:929]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\gthrsvc\plugin.cxx  
08/04/2012 07:28:16.08  mssearch.exe (0x1918)                       0x16CC  SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI                        ds7h    High        CPluginCollection::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content b9a315d3-1e4b-4ffb-8366-9e5cd5c5f0bb-crawl-0 )  [plugin.cxx:929]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\gthrsvc\plugin.cxx
```

In the craw log of central administration I get an Crawl Error with "Object reference not set to an instance to an object". But as far as I can say (changed debugger settings to NullReferenceException) this one is not thrown in my connector code.

After unsuccessful trials to debug the issue, I also updated Sharepoint to SP1 and June 2012 CU and installed SP1 for Search Server Express.  But that didn't solve the problem. (It even made the thing worse: before the GetAccessUri-Method in INamingContainer got called for every changed id, that isn't the case after update).

So the questions are:

What I'm doing wrong?
Is this a known issue? (Found hints on the net, that other people have the same issue)
What is the right way to impl. this.
I would really appreciate any input of experts and insiders, as our possibilities to debug this issue came to a dead end here.

Best Regards

---

Joachim

Comment: Joachim,
Any more information on this? I am in the same boat: it seems (from what others have experienced), that changelog crawls may not be supported with Custom connectors. Most annoying.
As to your problem: exceptions during the method execution will result in a crawl abort, so that has to be fixed.

Comment: Hey, unfortunatly I was not able to resolve this. So I changed back to a LastModifiedTimeStampField. To be honest: This part of Sharepoint (as many others) are not designed to be extended from an 3rd party developer. We now try to avoid this kind of development whenever we can.